# Need XSLT to use param which holds dynamic value, create an XML and validate against XSD

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a param "abc" that holds the following dynamic xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<hello type="PROCESS"><process urn="hello"><object></object><object></object></process></hello>
```

I need an XSLT to consume the property "abc" and create the desired xml.

> XSLT that I tried.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://tempuri.org/">
<xsl:param name="abc"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($abc)"  disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

I receive error while applying this XSLT: Exception Type System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.

> Desired xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<hello type="PROCESS"><process urn="hello"><object></object><object></object></process></hello>
```

Comment: There must be a mistake, because your Desired.xml is exactly the same as the input. Also please post things that you have already tried and describe what didn't work.

Comment: but my input is in a property "abc". I need to convert that to the desired xml using xslt.

Comment: I understand what you say, but it doesn't make sense if "abc" is exactly the same as the desired xml. (and this is what your description says).

Comment: I added a sample XSLT that I tried. I hope that helps.

Comment: So you actually want to output exactly the same XML as given?

Comment: You are missing a trailing `?` in your XML declaration _processing instruction_. It should look like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`. _Processing instructions_ start with `<?` and end with `?>`.

Comment: Please show the minimal but complete C# code to reproduce the error as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I did not put it in right words. Instead of param holding a dynamic xml, I said it as a property which confused lot of people here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the param which holds dynamic xml was not working for some reason. So I created a root, stripped the xml declaration and loaded the dynamic xml within the root.

I created XSD against the root element and it worked.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:param name="abc"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<myRoot>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($abc,'>')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</myRoot>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you for everyone who pitched in and helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the entire XML document tree like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[xsl:copy-of documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256183(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The xml is in a property $abc

Comment: In your description you say C# property "abc", which means a property of a class like `myObject.abc`. But in your example, you have xsl parameter "abc", I am confused. Please define what is a property for you. If you have it in the xsl parameter, then you could just do `<xsl:value-of select = "$abc" />`, but I don't see what's the point of this exercise. What problem do you have with your solution?

Comment: Sorry for wording it wrong. "abc" is a param which would get dynamic xml. I need to convert the param into a xml, validate against xsd to make sure I received the right xml.

Comment: your solution helped me get to the right one. Thanks for your help.